# Does Higgs field exert pressure which contributes to the stress-energy tensor causing gravity?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, higgs, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

First of all, I have never studied quantum field theory.

Since Higgs field is a scalar field, does Higgs field also exert positive/negative pressure which contributes to the stress-energy tensor causing attractive/repulsive gravity?

Comment: You're looking for something similar to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress-energy_tensor#Scalar_field Only more complicated because of the form of the Higgs potential.